# Move UIView With Deceleration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touch

I have a need to tap and drag a UIView on the screen with deceleration.  I have written the code very nicely for moving the view with touches, but need the object to keep moving with a certain degree of inertia (once a certain acceleration threshold is met), decelerating until it stops, or meets the boundary of the screen.  This is not for a game, but using some standard UIView controls.  The biggest part I am grappling with is the acceleration.

Any good algorithms that you have written to accomplish the same?

Edit:

I am using an animation block on the `touchesEnded:` method, but there is a noticeable delay between the time that a person lets go of their finger and the animation kicks in:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self 
                  duration:UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == 
                               UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ? 0.33f : 0.33f * 2.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut 
                animations:^(void){
                        if (dir == 1)   //  Flicked left
                        {
                            self.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5f,
                                                      self.center.y);
                        }
                        else {  //  Flicked right
                            self.center = CGPointMake(
                                self.superview.bounds.size.width - 
                                  (self.frame.size.width * 0.5f), self.center.y);
                        }
                     } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // Do nothing
                }];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the timing function used for the animation. The animation should be as fast as the user's dragging in the first, and quickly decelerates. The following code shows a very simple example of implementing this behavior.

First, in my `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method, I recorded the first touch location to my point buffer. I'm buffering two touch locations to get the movement vector of the view, and there could be different ways of getting the vector.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ivar_lastPoint[0] = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    ivar_lastPoint[1] = ivar_lastPoint[0];
    ivar_touchOffset.x = ivar_lastPoint[0].x - self.sprite.position.x;
    ivar_touchOffset.y = ivar_lastPoint[0].y - self.sprite.position.y;
    self.lastTime = [NSDate date];
}
```

Then, in `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method, I updated the location of the view. Actually, I used a CALayer rather than a view, as I want to use a custom timing function for its animation. So, I update the location of the layer according to the user, and for a given interval, I update the location buffers.

```
#define kSampleInterval 0.02f

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    /* First of all, move the object */
    CGPoint currentPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPoint center = self.sprite.position;
    center.x = currentPoint.x - ivar_touchOffset.x;
    center.y = currentPoint.y - ivar_touchOffset.y;
    self.sprite.position = center;

    /* Sample locations */
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.lastTime];
    if (interval > kSampleInterval) {
        ivar_lastPoint[0] = ivar_lastPoint[1];
        ivar_lastPoint[1] = currentPoint;
        self.lastTime = currentTime;
        self.lastInterval = interval;

    }
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

`self.sprite` is a reference to the CALayer object on my view. I don't need animation for dragging so I disabled it by using CATransaction class object.

Finally, I calculate the vector and apply the animation in `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method. Here, I created a custom CAMediaTimingFunction, so it's really "fast-in, ease-out".

```
#define kDecelerationDuration 1.0f
#define kDamping 5.0f

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint targetPoint;
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval interval = self.lastInterval + [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.lastTime];
    targetPoint.x = self.sprite.position.x + (ivar_lastPoint[1].x - ivar_lastPoint[0].x)/interval*kDecelerationDuration/kDamping;
    targetPoint.y = self.sprite.position.y + (ivar_lastPoint[1].y - ivar_lastPoint[0].y)/interval*kDecelerationDuration/kDamping;
    if (targetPoint.x < 0) {
        targetPoint.x = 0;
    } else if (targetPoint.x > self.bounds.size.width) {
        targetPoint.x = self.bounds.size.width;
    }
    if (targetPoint.y < 0) {
        targetPoint.y = 0;
    } else if (targetPoint.y > self.bounds.size.height) {
        targetPoint.y = self.bounds.size.height;
    }
    CAMediaTimingFunction *timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:
                                             0.1f : 0.9f :0.2f :1.0f];

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:kDecelerationDuration] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:timingFunction];

    self.sprite.position = targetPoint; 
    [CATransaction commit];

}
```

This is a very simple example. You may want a better vector-getting mechanism. Also, this only move a visual component (CALayer). You would probably need an UIView object to handle events from the object. In this case, you might want to animate through CALayer, and move the actual UIView object separately. There could be multiple ways of handling the CALayer animation and UIView relocation together.

Comment: I realized that animating in `touchesMoved:withEvent:` would not work for your case, because in this case, you shouldn't begin the animation before the user take off a finger. However, I also realized the time difference between when you commit an animation and when it actually begins should not matter in simply moving an view. The problem is rather in the timing function, so the beginning of the animation should be fast enough to feel like the movement is continuous. See my updated answer for the code.

Answer (score 3):

Use Core Animation. It's pretty straightforward if you look at the docs for UIView -- create an animation that sets the final position of the view, and specify UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut as the timing curve. The whole thing will take you just a handful of lines to implement.

Comment: I already have that part, but it's maintaining the acceleration that's a bit more tricky.  See the comment I left for Scott's post.

Comment: Great -- so it sounds like you're already using Core Animation to move the view around. When the touch ends, you create one more animation as above. Scale both the distance from the current location to the final location and the animation duration according to the current velocity of the view. I'm guessing that this is more about making it look nice than having an accurate physics model, but if you want more control over the deceleration curve you could do a short series of linked animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constant acceleration for the object to stop moving at a constant rate of slow down.  Or you can make the acceleration increase or decrease depending on if you want the deceleration to be quicker/slower towards the point of reaching zero velocity.

```
struct Velocity {
float x;
float y; }
```

`Vector acceleration = your acceleration equation. // can be constant`

`Vector newVelocity = oldVelocity + acceleration * timeDelta;`

`Vector newPosition = newVelocity * timeDelta;`

assuming you have a normalized vector for your direction of travel, and you are just countering that direction you can use float instead of Vector.

You have to bound the newPosition on the border.  And you have to stop iterating per time delta when velocity becomes negative.

Comment: So that's a great answer for creating vectors, but how do I implement that within the context of a UIView and touch events.  My current implementation takes a timestamp of when touches begin and when they end, plus the position of the view when touches begin and when it ends.  I then use an animation block to animate the view from one end to the other, but there is a noticeable lag from the time that the touch ends and when the animation executes.  How do I make that more fluid?